# C# floating point literals : Why compiler does not DEFAULTS to the left hand side variable type

Tags: c#

To declare float numbers we need to put 'f' for floats and 'd' for doubles.

Example:

```
float num1 = 1.23f;   // float stored as float

float num2 = 1.23;    // double stored as float. The code won't compile in C#.
```

It is said that C# defaults to double if a floating point literal is omitted.

My question, is what prevents a modern language like 'C#' to 'DEFAULTS' to the left hand side variable type? After all, the compiler can see the entire line of code.

Is this for historic reasons in compiler design? or Is there something I'm not getting.

Comment: Your num2 assignment won't compile - 1.23 is taken as a double literal and cannot be assigned to a float variable.

Comment: Nothing prevents it other than the compiler writers did not implement it.

Comment: @mikez In other words, nothing prevents it except the language prevents it. The question is why.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes exactly. Questions like this are typically tautological. If Eric Lippert chimes in, I bet he'll say something like "we didn't do it because we never decided it was worth doing over other things."

Comment: @mikez Or they might have very good, documented reasons for it, given that, say, C or C++, allow a type conversion that lets you assign from a double to a float. Like "we judged implicit type conversions are usually a source of errors."

Comment: For those of us that rarely think about language issues (raises hand), its an interesting enough observation. I know why I can type `int a = 1` and `float b = 1`. It seems like I should be able to, even if its contrived, do the same for float and double.

Comment: @juanchopanza I highly doubt you find such a reason written anywhere. May be there is a language design principle here, but I doubt it. The compiler already auto converts integer literals to float or double automatically. It could easily do the same with range checking on floating point literals.

Comment: @RitchMelton It's not that it's a poor question. I'll never fault anyone for wishing that the C# compiler was more willing to (accurately) predict what they wanted. But, in the absence of that ability, I personally think it's fairly clear why they decided that 1.23 is a `double` literal rather than a `float` literal.

Comment: @mikez Auto-converts when you've explicitly provided a type to which you want to assign an lvalue, yes. But what about `var`? Doesn't it get a different kind of strange if you allow `float f = 1.0` but the type of `var d = 1.0` is `double`? To me, this seems like one of the sacrifices you make in favor of being able to use implicit typing.

Comment: @furkle Do you think its weird that `float i = 1` but `var i = 1` is `int`?

Comment: @mikez The literal `1` is an `int`. It is possible to implicitly cast an `int` to a `float`, because no data is lost. The other way is not possible. `int i = 5.0f` will not compile. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx

Comment: @mikez A little, yeah, but there's not really any similar types colliding there. It's very clear that `float i = 1` is casting `1` to `1.0f` in some sense, because there's not really a functional overlap between `int` and `float`. All you're doing is adding a boatload of precision to 1. `float` and `double` are a question of precision, not function, so I feel like it gets both functionally and philosophically more difficult dealing with the concept of what a `1.23` literal is, and how that gets predicted contextually.

Comment: I had a quick look through the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) with no luck, but maybe I missed something. If not, maybe you can find other specification documents that will have the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else here can probably explain why the .NET developers decided against using some sort of prediction to determine how a number literal should be shoehorned into the type you're providing to it. But in the absence of any sort of philosophy, the answer is simple: they didn't want to do that, so they didn't. I'm not going to tell you that you outright shouldn't care about this, because of course it's not totally unreasonable to want a compiler to understand exactly what you want. It'd at least be nice, right?

(If I *had* to guess, though, I'd say it has a lot to do with allowing some sort of logical implicit typing - `float f = 1.0` is `float`, but `var d = 1.0` is `double`? This gets even less logical when you consider that f.Equals(d) would be `false`, despite the fact that `1.0 == 1.0` is `true`.)

But, assuming they had good reasons not to introduce any type-definition-specific prediction (and some more perfectly good reasons can be found in Rotem's post), the best reason I can imagine they decided that `double num1 = 1.23` is acceptable, and `float num1 = 1.23` is not, is that `double` is frankly more useful in most cases. The CPU and IO penalties of using a 64-bit floating point value as opposed to 32-bit are negligible in most use cases, but the usefulness of not having to worry about exceeding the bounds of that data type is significant.

Note that you could make the exact same argument about why `1.23` can't be assigned to a `decimal` without a suffix. The people who designed C# decided it was easier to make assumptions about the type of a number literal of any given format, and `double` is a totally reasonable assumption given that the majority of people who write `1.23` want a `double`, or at least should be using one.

edit: user fixed title.

Answer (score 7):

I would say the main reason is that of predictability and consistency.

Let's imagine you are the compiler and you have to determine the type of the literal `3.14` in the following statements:

---

```
float p = 3.14;
```

The first one was easy. Obviously, should be a float.

---

What about this one?

```
var x = 3.14 * 10.0f;
```

The user explicitly added an `f` after `10.0`. So that should be a `float`, what 
about `3.14`? Should `x` be a `double` or a `float`?

---

And this one:

```
bool b = 3.14 / 3.14f == 1;
```

Is the first `3.14` a  `double` or a `float`? The value of `b` depends on it!

---

As a user, I'd rather explicitly add an `f` and know **exactly** what I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

Because the feature you are proposing would basically make the compiler inconsistent. The rule is simple and easily understandable: `3.14` is a `double`, `3.14f` is a `float`.

Your example is trivial, but your looking at the small picture:

```
float x = 3.14;
```

Ok let's say the compiler is "smart" enough to resolve the literal to float.

```
double x = 3.14;
```

Hmmm, now the same literal is a `double` and there is no implicit conversion from `float` to `double`...weird. So what should the type of the follwoing be?

```
var x = 3.14;
```

Other similar variants of the same issue:

```
int i = 2 * 3.14;
```

What should the compile time error be? Can't implicitly convert `double` to `int` or `float` to `int`. Why would one be better than the other?

```
var x = 2 * 3.14;
```

Oh, oh, now what?

The C# designers decided that a decimal number literal be resolved as a `double`...always. If you want another type (`float` or `decimal`), you need to explicitly specify it. Advantage: consistency. They could have very well decided to make `float` the implicit type but you can't have it both ways without making a mess out of it.

Also, it's important to note that C# resolution rules (types, methods, etc.) consistently ignore the type of the left side of an expression. Your feature would make the compiler change its type resolution based on the type of the left side which would also be inconsistent with how the language behaves.

Comment: pretty enlightening comments and answers from everybody, i can only accept one answer.